# Run Mercure on production with Symfony and Apache | HTTPS problem

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ssl, mercure

i have a symfony app and i'm using Mercure.

To run Mercure i use this command

```
SERVER_NAME=:3000 MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='something' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='something' CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://my-domain.cz ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1 ./mercure run -config Caddyfile
```

I have installed SSL certificate from Let's encrypt authority.
My apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
....
ProxyRequests off
<LocationMatch /mercure>
ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000

...
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my-domain.cz
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Issue. When i'm trying to subscribe some topic a receive this error

```
GET https://my-domain.cz:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=someGoodTopic net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

If i will try to get this URL from browser i will get the same issue, but if i will try to use http:// everything will be OK, but unfortunately i can't make request for http from my https domain.

```
(Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain.cz/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure EventSource endpoint 'http://my-domain.cz:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=someGoodTopic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.)
```

I will be glad if someone can help me =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer but your error may be related to allowing anonymous connections to mercure. Other than that it looks fine. I setup mercure over https not to long ago and there wasn't really anything specific that needed to be done. Try setting up authentication with mercure and let me know how it goes.